# Нужно ли всё экранирование encodeURIComponent?

Tags: javascript, url, безопасность

Понятно, что `encodeURIComponent` нужен чтобы предотвратить неоднозначности в парсинге url, а также избежать проблем с кодировкой. Но действительно ли всё производимое экранирование требуется для query-параметров (именно для них, а не для любой части адреса)? Например, следующие ссылки работают одинаково:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=[1,{"a":"b"}]
https://www.google.com/search?q=%5B1%2C%7B%22a%22%3A%22b%22%7D%5D
```

[image: скриншот]

Я хочу сделать более красивый адрес, для чего требуется отказаться от экранирования скобок, кавычек, двоеточия и запятой. Безопасно ли так поступать, может ли что-то сломаться и не появятся ли из-за этого какие-то уязвимости?

```js
function beautifulEncode(s) {
  return encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/%../g, m => ({
    "%5B": '[',
    "%5D": ']',
    "%7B": '{',
    "%7D": '}',
    "%2C": ',',
    "%3A": ':',
    "%22": '"',
  }[m] || m))
}

console.log(beautifulEncode(JSON.stringify([1, {a: "b"}])))
console.log(beautifulEncode(JSON.stringify([1, {'A&B+1': "I'm here"}])))
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/62718860/4928642)

Comment: Какая бд используется?

Comment: @icYFTL, какое это вообще имеет отношение к БД?

Comment: RFC 3986 описывает эти символы как зарезервированные, которые следует (should) экранировать. Правда, причину я не совсем понял, но вроде бы суть в том, что в некоторых схемах URI эти символы могут выполнять какую-то разделительную роль, но к http-ссылкам это вроде бы не очень относится

Comment: Кстати, если посмотреть запрос, который отправляет Firefox, то получается `GET /search?q=[1,{%22a%22:%22b%22}] HTTP/1.1`

Comment: @andreymal, хром тоже. Но заэкранировались только кавычки, остальные символы - нет. Но при переходе по такой ссылке в адресной строке показывается оригинальная ссылка с кавычками. Мне хочется отображение красивое, а серверу вроде всё равно что парсить.

Comment: @andreymal, ну если говорить про хост, то ipv6-адрес пишется с квадратными скобками и двоеточиями, так что http тоже касается. Но у меня вопрос именно про query.

Comment: @Qwertiy просто интересно. А еще интереснее сколько  колумнов в таблице с паролями

Comment: @icYFTL, скорее всего эти параметры будут использоваться только на фронте. На сервере C#, он параметры парсит стандартными средствами (впрочем, я ещё не проверил, что IIS не против таких параметров). А MSSQL не имеет к вопросу никакого отношения.

Comment: Брррр. ASP.net. >:(

Comment: @icYFTL, ASP.NET MVC. Кстати, SO тоже на нём работал, пока с год назад не начал переход на .NET Core.

Comment: Люблю C#. Но не ASP.net. На нем токо китайцы прошивки пишут. Никогда не понимал зачем брать этот ASP, если есть заточенные под бэк NodeJS ну или на крайняк Python3 + Django. Хотя C# и разрабатывался как веб решение...